# Can I detect programmatically if Android is connected to a wireless network but needs to sign in?

Tags: android, wireless

Can I detect programmatically if **I'm connected to a wireless but need to sign in on a login page**?

I wish to detect when the device shows the notification "**Sign in to Wi-Fi network**":

[image: notification example]

And also detect when the user logs in successfully.